# C# DateTimePicker rollover problems

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have DateTimePicker controls with a custom format to show hours/minutes as well as the date ("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm").  The problem I have is that if I use the up/down arrow keys to change the values they don't roll over properly when they overflow.

ex1
initial value 03/23/2011 16:58
Select minutes, hit the up arrow once:  value updates to 03/23/2011 16:59 as expected
Hit up arrow a second time:  value updates to 03/23/2011 16:00, not 17:00 as expected.

ex2
initial value 03/23/2011 16:00
Select minutes, hit the down arrow once:  value updates to 03/23/2011 16:59, not 15:59 as expected.

ex3
initial value 03/23/2011 23:03
Select hours, hit the up arrow once:  value updates to 03/23/2011 00:03, not 03/24/2011 00:03 as expected.

Edit:  The reason this is problematic on what I'm doing is that I'm using the DTPs to adjust the placement of objects on a timeline, and the default rollover results in the object jumping back.  This is aggravated by the order of the objects being fixed.  If two are at 16:05 and 16:59, the up arrow rollover on the 2nd would result in it changing to 16:00 which is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour of the DateTimePicker.

Comment: Maybe in Redmond, but not for anyone who's used my app.  I guess that means I'm going to need to do a lot of processing in the value changed event to override the defaults.